# Boot partition keeps filling up with old inird.img files

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg, initrd

Here are the contents of `/boot`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     3072 Apr 18 09:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root     4096 Mar 22 15:43 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217495 Jan 17 05:59 config-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217457 Feb 28 02:45 config-4.15.0-91-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Mar 22 15:50 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 60196828 Apr 18 09:05 initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 60206115 Apr 18 09:05 initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Feb 13  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4068355 Jan 17 05:59 System.map-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8367768 Jan 17 06:27 vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8375960 Feb 28 02:51 vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
```

My kernel version is `4.15.0-91-generic` (based on `uname -r`).

The output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` is:

```
c  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic                               4.15.0-74.84                                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-76-generic                               4.15.0-76.86                                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-91-generic                               4.15.0-91.92                                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ic  linux-image-4.4.0-171-generic                               4.4.0-171.200                                    amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

This is what happens when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.17) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-69-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-69-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-69-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_BapeFK/lib/modules/3.19.0-69-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_BapeFK/lib/modules/3.19.0-69-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-66-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oFrhwW/lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oFrhwW/lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-65-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-65-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cmnh3Q/lib/modules/3.19.0-65-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_cmnh3Q/lib/modules/3.19.0-65-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-59-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_kimz35/lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_kimz35/lib/modules/3.19.0-59-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-58-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_yH46Fl/lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_yH46Fl/lib/modules/3.19.0-58-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_gmb7aZ/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_gmb7aZ/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirplatformgraphics.conf: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, the contents of /boot are:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     3072 Apr 18 09:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root     4096 Mar 22 15:43 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217495 Jan 17 05:59 config-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217457 Feb 28 02:45 config-4.15.0-91-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     1024 Mar 22 15:50 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16975438 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-3.19.0-58-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16975489 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-3.19.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16975434 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16975144 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-3.19.0-66-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 16975428 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-3.19.0-69-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 60195966 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 60204841 Apr 18 09:14 initrd.img-4.15.0-91-generic
drwx------  2 root root    12288 Feb 13  2016 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4068355 Jan 17 05:59 System.map-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8367768 Jan 17 06:27 vmlinuz-4.15.0-76-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8375960 Feb 28 02:51 vmlinuz-4.15.0-91-generic
```

It appears that the system is trying to build old `initrd` files in `/boot`, and then `/boot` fills up, and then `dpkg` fails. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you been perhaps manually deleting files that were originally installed by the package manager?

Comment: I removed old images from `/boot`, per https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

Comment: None of the high-rated answers in that thread involve manually deleting files, which is the usual cause of the symptoms you are showing. I take it your real problem was that you /boot was full? And this is the result of trying to fix that problem? Exactly which answer did you follow? (each answer has it's own 'share' permalink). Did you follow *each* step carefully? Or did you skip steps? Were there error messages that you ignored?

Comment: Managing old kernels and `/boot` space has been a chronic problem since I started using Ubuntu many years ago. I'm usually careful to remove unused kernels with `apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic`. But recently, this has been failing because `/boot` keeps filling up with outdated initrd.img files whenever i run `apt-get upgrade`--even for kernels that do not appear in `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`. I tried to manually delete those initrd.img files from `/boot`, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: what happens if you add this ppa https://launchpad.net/~gerardpuig/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and install ubuntu-cleaner using apt?

Comment: What is th Ubuntu verson? The reason is quite clear to ne. But you've did lots of wrong things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove the residue files that tell `update-initramfs` which kernel is installed

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/3.19*
   ```
2. Confirm (there will be no 3.19* images get processed)

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
   ```
3. Go and fix apt installation

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

Then you can remove those 3.19* images, permanently.

Note: Step 2 is optional as it is repeated within Step 3 when installing `linux-firmware` package. I included it to be clear.

Comment: `sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/3.19*` was the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Carefully read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

As per this post you can remove old unused kernel simply with `autoremove` command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Note: `apt-get autoremove` will not remove all automatically installed old kernel providing packages as fallback versions are kept; the list of kept kernels is maintained and automatically updated in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` as a list of matching regular expressions. HENCE I wrote Read above post carefully.

List all the kernels, including the booted one:

```
dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+'
```

If you want to purge one specific kernel providing package you can do so via the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.**.*-**-generic
sudo dpkg --purge linux-headers-4.**.*-* linux-headers-4.**.*-**-generic
```

Above page also provide on how to "Safely Removing Old Kernels" including `initrd.img`. Better follow this step by step.

Comment: @OP, this is the best way to go about. Trust me, I speak from experience. All others are good, but one little typo and off goes your entire work

Comment: Also, if possible keep the img files upto 3 updates back. It helps when some application gets broken for a particular update :)

Comment: This seems unlikely to work for the OP, since by deleting files manually they have blocked apt ability to complete removals. A file-not-found error during removal will cause dpkg to error...which is what the OP's output seems to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your purges are only getting one of the six packages associated with a kernel, and the leftover pieces are causing problems.  For the 3.19 initrd file in /boot, take the numbwer, e.g. 3.19.0-58 and run that through your dpkg --list | fgrep 3.19.0-58. Run your apt-get purge on that list of 3.19 packages.  Then take the next one, until all have been fixed.
  Do this the next time you want to purge a full kernel -- get the associated packages with dpkg --list | fgrep x.y.z-w  then if only packages you want to delete are listed, feed that list to a purge (recall the command in the previous line to produce the list):

```
dpkg --list |fgrep x.y.z-w
apt-get purge `!!`
```

Answer (score 0):

**One reasonably safe solution** for most future readers:

For each no-such-file-or-directory, create a dummy file for apt to remove. Apt doesn't care about the file contents, it just needs to remove the file. So give it a file to remove.

This method can be tedious (you have a LOT) of missing files, but is much safer than the alternative below.

---

**EXAMPLE**

Here's one error:
`/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory`

Files in /etc are owned by root, so create a dummy file using `sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf`

Now there's a file for apt/dpkg to remove, which cures the no-such-file-or-directory error.

---

**A less safe solution** is to use dpkg's --force-remove-reinstreq flag. We call that the Nuclear Option - it removes the package entry in the dpkg database *without trying to remove any files*.

This seems likely to be an effective solution for you (and only you). All future readers should forget they saw it

**WARNING** Use --force-remove-reinstreq as A LAST RESORT before reinstalling. If you misuse it, you may break your package manager and require a reinstall. This option is for experienced users ONLY. This is strong medicine -- misused, it might kill the patient.